# Upload image to API Zendesk in Java

Tags: java, image, zendesk

I'm trying to upload an image to Zendesk API.

The upload is correct, but if the image is corrupted.

Here is my code. Did I miss something?

```java
private static final String API_URL = ConfigB2CSugar.getApiZendeskUrl() + "uploads.json";

public static DocumentResponse uploadToZendesk(File fileToUpload, String fileName) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    DocumentResponse responseMap = new DocumentResponse();

    try {
        String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileToUpload.getName());

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(API_URL+"?filename="+fileName);

        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addBinaryBody("file", fileToUpload)
                .build();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        
        httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + ConfigB2CSugar.getAuthTokenZendesk());
        httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);

        // Ejecutar la solicitud y obtener la respuesta
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        String jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        // Imprimir el código de estado de la respuesta
        System.out.println("Status Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        // Analizar la respuesta JSON y devolverla
        return DocumentResponse.parseJsonToDocument(jsonResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error al subir archivo.");
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Cerrar el cliente HTTP
        client.close();
    }

    // Devolver la respuesta
    return responseMap;
}
```